# Why does time complexity of HashSet<T>.IntersectWith depend on the equality comparers?

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity, hashset, set-intersection

I am referring to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Remarks:
>
> If the collection represented by the other parameter is a HashSet
>   collection with the same equality comparer as the current HashSet
>   object, this method is an O(n) operation. Otherwise, this method is an
>   O(n + m) operation, where n is Count and m is the number of elements
>   in other.

I am trying to understand what part the equality comparer plays.

If `other` is also a `HashSet`, intersection could work like this:

```
T[] array = this.ToArray(); // O(1)
foreach (T item in array) // iterate through this => O(n)
    if (!other.Contains(item)) // other is a HashSet => O(1)
        this.Remove(item); // this is a HashSet => O(1)
```

This makes a total of `O(n)`, as stated by MSDN. But as I understand it, it should always be `O(n)` if `other` is a `HashSet` - no matter what equality comparer it has!

If `other` is not a `HashSet`, we would have a larger complexity for `other.Contains` in the code snippet above (e.g. `O(log m)` for `SortedSet` or `O(m)` for `List`). Because we have nested operations, we must multiply the numbers (so `O(n*log m)` for `SortedSet` or `O(n*m)` for `List`) to get the total complexity, which is worse than the stated `O(n+m)`. So the approach for the case where `other` is not a `HashSet` seems to be different.

Maybe it is done like this:

```
HashSet<T> intersectionSet = new HashSet<T>(this.Comparer); // O(1)
foreach (T item in other) // iterate through other => O(m)
    if (this.Contains(item)) // this is a HashSet => O(1)
        intersectionSet.Add(item); // intersectionSet is a HashSet => O(1)
this.Clear(); // O(n)
foreach (T item in intersectionSet) // O(m) in the worst case, because intersectionSet can have at most m elements
    this.Add(item); // O(1)
```

So we get `O(m+n)` as stated by MSDN. Again, I cannot see what role the equality comparer plays in the complexity.

Since Microsoft put a lot of thought and manpower into designing/implementing `IntersectWith`, I believe that their version (where the equality comparer plays a role in the time complexity) is the best possible. So **I assume I have made some errors in reasoning. Can you point me to them?**

Comment: The statements : foreach()  [o(m)] * other.Contains(item) [o(n+m)].  Log m is when you have a binary tree which is a hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If other is also a `HashSet`, intersection could work like this:
>
> ```
> T[] array = this.ToArray(); // O(1)
> foreach (T item in array) // iterate through this => O(n)
>     if (!other.Contains(item)) // other is a HashSet => O(1)  A
>         this.Remove(item); // this is a HashSet => O(1)       B
> ```

This would be an incorrect implementation if the two hash sets use different equality comparers. The line I marked with A would use `other`'s equality comparer, the line I marked with `B` would use `this`'s equality comparer. Therefore, the line `other.Contains(item)` checks the wrong thing: it checks whether `other` thinks it contains `item`. What it *should* be checking is whether `this` thinks that `other` contains `item`.

---

But aside from the array creation (which is not O(1), and which Microsoft can avoid by using `HashSet`'s private fields), what you came up with is pretty much what you can see in [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs.html#42c5b5a376261a64) Microsoft actually does in the case that the equality comparers match.